# EF6. Make sure "System.Data.Entity.Properties.Resources.PowerShell.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "EntityFramework"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-6

I have ASP.NET MVC project and use EF6 in it.
Till this point everything was working fine.

Recently however I did some refactor and move classes a bit. Entity in the project works fine unless I try to do `Add-Migration` or `Update-Database`.

Then I Get this error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. 
Make sure "System.Data.Entity.Properties.Resources.PowerShell.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly 
"EntityFramework" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

I investigated the issue but I don't have any Resource.resx files to change.

If I need one please help me create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been found.
I needed to update Entity Framework from 6.2 to 6.4